# Adding Sub-domain in Route53 for CloudFront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I followed the steps on creating sub-domain via Route53 by creating a new Hosted Zone for cdn.domain.com and added the NS to the registrar in addition to the root domain, domain.com NS.

I then added Alternate Domain Name in the CloudFront Distribution that reads cdn.domain.com and saved it. I then waited for the status to get deployed.

My question is,

1. Do I still need to add an A record for the sub-domain that I created? If so, where will it route?
2. If I don't need to create an A Record, shall I add a new record CNAME on the root domain Hosted Zone or on the sub-domain Hosted Zone? Because I see no target Available.

IPV6 is also enabled on the CloudFront Distribution. Please advise on what would be my next step.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the method of multiple hosted zones for the same domain, be sure to use the correct NS servers. (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zone-public-considerations.html))

The simple approach is to on the root domain add an A record for the **subdomain**, with an alias set to the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Thank you! In addition, I was able to make it work by using the root domain's Hosted Zone and added cdn.domain.com A and AAA, then after a while the Alias or CloudFront appeared and it started to resolve. Also, noted that I changed the SSL from my Distribution Settings from CloudFront to my own Wildcard SSL because it was having unsecured issues. After a few hours, everything went smooth. Thank you for your assistance Lior!